# "Greedy" search & replace for sed

Tags: bash, sed

I have a bash function to get a prefix from a string up to and including the character "-".

```
get_prefix_with_hyphen() {
  # get prefix with trailing hyphen
  prefix_with_hyphen=$(echo "$1" | sed 's/-.*$/-/')
  if [ "$prefix_with_hyphen" = "$1" ]; then
    echo ""
  else
    echo "$prefix_with_hyphen"
  fi
}
```

This works perfectly for "", "string" and "a-string":

```
echo $(get_prefix_with_hyphen "")

echo $(get_prefix_with_hyphen "string")

echo $(get_prefix_with_hyphen "a-string")
a-
```

But if there are two or more hyphens in the string, it returns everything up to and including the **first** hyphen. I'd like it to include everything up to and including the **last** hyphen:

```
echo $(get_prefix_with_hyphen "a-long-string")
a-
# would like to return "a-long-"
```

How do I do this to implement a "greedy" pattern match in sed or some other tool?

There's an additional "if" statement in the function as well. Is it possible to remove that and somehow use a different regular expression to achieve the same result?

Comment: re: *`There's an additional "if" statement in the function as well. Is it possible to remove that and somehow use a different regular expression to achieve the same result?`* - it's not clear (to me) what this *additional "if" statement* looks let alone how/if it can be replaced with *a different regular expression*; at this point you have a couple answers that address your main question; if you're unable to expand these answers to address this *additional "if" statement* then consider asking a new question, making sure to provide the necessary details to understand the requirement

Answer (score 5):

An alternative approach using [parameter substitution](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html)

```
get_prefix_with_hyphen() { 
    prefix_with_hyphen="${1%-*}"                  # parameter substitution; NOTE: removes trailing '-'
    if [ "$prefix_with_hyphen" = "$1" ]; then
       echo ""
    else 
       prefix_with_hyphen+="-"                    # make sure to append trailing '-'
       echo "${prefix_with_hyphen}"
    fi
}
```

**NOTE:** this has the added benefit of eliminating the current performance overhead of spawning two subshells (`echo | sed`)

Taking for a test drive:

```
$ get_prefix_with_hyphen ""

$ get_prefix_with_hyphen "string"

$ get_prefix_with_hyphen "a-string"
a-
$ get_prefix_with_hyphen "a-long-string"
a-long-
```

Answer (score 2):

Technically, your pattern is already greedy: the `.*` matches as much as possible, which it why it's consuming *all* the hyphens.

To make that pattern non-greedy, you can use `-[^-]*$` to match a hyphen followed by only non-hyphen characters.

Alternately, as you suggest in your question, you can use a greedy quantifier to slurp up the characters *before the **last** hyphen*:

```bash
$ echo a-b-c-d-e | sed 's/-.*$/-/'
a-

$ echo a-b-c-d-e | sed -E 's/(.*-).*$/\1/'
a-b-c-d-
```

Comment: When you want to return an empty string when there is no hyphen, use `sed 's/[^-]*$//'`.

Answer (score 2):

I like a `case` statement for this, and certainly parameter expansion.

```
$: get_prefix_with_hyphen(){ case $1 in *-*) echo "${1%-*}-";; *) echo; return 1;; esac; }

$: for v in "" string a-string a-long-string; do get_prefix_with_hyphen "$v"; done


a-
a-long-

$: set -x; for v in "" string a-string a-long-string; do get_prefix_with_hyphen "$v" && echo ok || echo no; done
+ for v in "" string a-string a-long-string
+ get_prefix_with_hyphen ''
+ case $1 in
+ echo

+ return 1
+ echo no
no
+ for v in "" string a-string a-long-string
+ get_prefix_with_hyphen string
+ case $1 in
+ echo

+ return 1
+ echo no
no
+ for v in "" string a-string a-long-string
+ get_prefix_with_hyphen a-string
+ case $1 in
+ echo a-
a-
+ echo ok
ok
+ for v in "" string a-string a-long-string
+ get_prefix_with_hyphen a-long-string
+ case $1 in
+ echo a-long-
a-long-
+ echo ok
ok
```

If for some reason you prefer `sed`, just remove non-hyphens at the end with `s/[^-]*$//` for the same result.

```
$: for v in "" string a-string a-long-string; do echo "$v" | sed 's/[^-]*$//'; done


a-
a-long-
```

This logic can also be used with parameter expansion to avoid the `sed` if you turn on extended globbing.

```
$: shopt -s extglob; for v in "" string a-string a-long-string; do echo "${v/%+([^-])}"; done


a-
a-long-
```

Which means if you set extended globbing in your script, the function can be very short and sweet for existing functionality (i.e., without the error return on no match):

```
shopt -s extglob
get_prefix_with_hyphen(){ echo "${1/%+([^-])}"; }
```

but to contain the extended globbing to *just* the function if you needed, your easiest bet would be, ironically, a subshell...

```
get_prefix_with_hyphen(){ ( shopt -s extglob; echo "${1/%+([^-])}" ); }
```

You could check it, and set it back to previous state, but most idioms that do that spawn a subshell, too, so I'd just use the case statement, or the `sed` for portability.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to spawn a subshell to call `sed` for this; `bash` can do it on its own:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

get_prefix_with_hyphen() {
    local pfx ret=1

    if [[ $1 =~ .*- ]]; then
        ret=0
        pfx=${BASH_REMATCH[0]}
    fi

    # after testing change below to just: printf '%s\n' "$pfx"
    printf '"%s" -> "%s", returning "%s"\n' "$1" "$pfx" "$ret"

    return "$ret"
}

get_prefix_with_hyphen ''
get_prefix_with_hyphen 'string'
get_prefix_with_hyphen 'a-string'
get_prefix_with_hyphen 'a-long-string'
```

```
$ ./tst.sh
"" -> "", returning "1"
"string" -> "", returning "1"
"a-string" -> "a-", returning "0"
"a-long-string" -> "a-long-", returning "0"
```

I'm setting a return code for the function above so it returns a failure indication if the input doesn't match the regexp, same as `grep` does.

Comment: Excellent, great solutions!

Answer (score 0):

```
get_prefix_with_hyphen() {
   sed '/-/!g;s/[^-]*$//' <<<"$*"
}
```

If the line does not contain a hyphen, `g`rab the hold space. Because hold space is empty, it will replace the line by empty line. Then, remove from the line from the end everything up until the last hyphen.